# Criticality of a graph

Tags: graph-theory

What's the usual method for proving the criticality of a graph?

I've been trying out different methods and theorems but I can't find a decent method that's really convincing.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Wondering what a critical graph is? Wikipedia tells us that a graph is critical if removing any vertex or edge results in the chromatic number decreasing (by one).

Comment: A graph is critical if every one of its proper subgraphs (subgraph not equal to the original) has a chromatic color less than the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ is $n$-critical (i.e. $\chi(G) = n$), then $\delta(G) \geq n-1$. So if $\delta(G) < n-1$ then $G$ is not $n$-critical.

Comment: I'm going to assume that delta is the degree of any vertex? And is this an actual theorem?

Comment: If $G$ is $n$-critical then it is the complete graph.

Comment: Yuval- the 5-cycle is 3-critical (deleting any vertex gives a bipartite graph), but it is not the complete graph.